# Parallel filesystem which schedules simultaneous file requests to mutually exclusive sets of OSSs

Tags: high-availability, hpc, lustre

My environment is RHEL based, interconnect is infiniband. 
I have some experience with Lustre. What i want to know is:

1. Is there a parallel file-system, where if simultaneous write request arrive, they are scheduled on mutually exclusive sets of object servers (to get high fault-tolerance)?
2. If not, could i tune lustre to schedule simultaneous file-write request on different target disks? I don't mind if i have to disable striping.

**Improving fault tolerance while compromising with performance is okay for me.**
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Lustre does not do data replication for high availability. I believe you can do this with in Gluster but it requires some forethought in regards to replicas. There is also a geo-replication module which can be used to replicate changes off-site but I think it is a separate back end process.